# 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE_LOBS_TO_EXTFILE' is not recognized as a function or procedure

Tags: database, file, export, derby

I am using derby database. Using a prepared statement and executing.
I dont have problem with non-BLOB field tables. If a table has a blob and trying to export to a file. Then this error comes. Please help me resolve it. I think I am not giving the statement properly. Please guide me. Attaching my code here. Thanks in advance.

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = 
  connect.prepareStatement("CALL SYSCS_UTIL
                            .SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE_LOBS_TO_EXTFILE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
statement.setString(1, null);
statement.setString(2, "xyz");
statement.setString(3, "c:/derbytest/xyz.csv");
statement.setString(4, null);
statement.setString(5, null);
statement.setString(6, null);
statement.setString(7, "c:/derbytest/xyz.dat");

statement.executeUpdate();
statement.close();
```

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: 'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE_LOBS_TO_EXTFILE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepare_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using a version of Derby which is too old? This procedure was added to Derby in release 10.3.1.4 by DERBY-378. See https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/db/derby/code/tags/10.3.1.4/RELEASE-NOTES.html?view=co

With many of the system procedures, if you give it the wrong number of arguments when trying to prepare the call, you get a terrible message; that's DERBY-2859: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-2859

But it looks like you gave the right number of arguments.

If you can reproduce this with a small standalone test program, I'd recommend contacting the derby-dev mailing list and asking them if this is a bug.

There are Derby regression tests which exercise SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE_LOBS_TO_EXTFILE so it's not like that functionality is flat-out broken.

I think the compiler is just not giving you a very good error message.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Thanks for the reply.
I have changed the version to 10.3.1.4. I am still getting same error.

Here it is:
Apache Derby Network Server - 10.3.1.4 - (561794) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527 at 2013-11-19 18:42:41.965 GMT

'SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_QUERY_LOBS_TO_EXTFILE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.

Comment: Did you do a full upgrade of your existing database when you installed the newer version of Derby? If not, you'll need to do that. Here's some info: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/tdevupgradedb.html